# c# infragistics ultratree или обычное treeView. Рекурсивное заполнение + добавление колонки для внесения данных

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Есть Класс по которому будет строиться дерево.

Поля Класса: `Id`, `ParentId`, `Name` и т д несущественные поля, то есть источник данных дерева - `List<MyClass>`.
Дерево хочу вывести в treeView или ultraTree от Infragistics 
Ветка дерева это экземпляр класса указанного выше.. ну а выводится пусть Name

Я хочу это дерево вывести, при этом изначально количество вложенностей я не знаю. Надо выводить рекурсивно, как это сделать я не знаю.

Следующая задача. Как к этому дереву прикрепить колонку, в которой я б вводил необходимые мне значения. И потом бы эти значения хранил в отдельном классе.

Заранее спасибо за понимание и ответ.

Comment: каким образом ты его вывести хочешь? В Treeview или в консольку обход дерева вывести. Что есть источник? Код Node-а дерева добавь.

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Хочу в Treeview вывести... Ветка - экземпляр класса, ну а выводится пусть name

Answer (score 1):

Давай по порядку тогда. 
xaml:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:INode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

DataContext окна соответственно:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private readonly IDataService _dataService;

        private INode _selectedNode;


        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Public Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Отправная точка, главная ViewModel.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            Contract.Assert(dataService != null);
            _dataService = dataService;
        }

        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public Properties


        public List<INode> Nodes { get; private set; }

        public INode SelectedNode
        {
            get { return _selectedNode; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedNode != value)
                {
                    _selectedNode = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }



    #endregion Public Properties
}
```

и сам INode:

```
 public interface INode
    {
        #region Public Properties 

        string Name { get; }

        List<INode> Nodes { get; } 

        #endregion Public Properties
    }
```

соответственно надо добавить к ним стандартную обвязку в виде сервис-локатора( что бы просунуть контекст окну или явно это сделать) и реализацию интерфейса INode. Все остальное зависит от задач. Выделенный узел, раскрытие каскадом и т.п.